# From class to .cpp

Tags: class, object

I was attempting to make a simple pokemon text game in c++. 
I created a class for pokemon, and then in my pokemain.cpp tried outputting hp from charmander.
When i try running my pokemonmain.cpp, it says charmander was not declared. Im sure this is a dumb question, but I cant find an answer to it.

Here is my code.

```
//class named stats
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class pokemon
{
    int health, damage;

    public: 

    pokemon (int,int);
    int hp() 
    {
        return (health);
    }

    int dmg()
    {
        return (damage);
    }

};

pokemon::pokemon (int hp, int dmg)
{
    health = hp;
    damage = dmg;


    pokemon charmander (25,3);
    pokemon bulbasaur (20,4);
    pokemon squirtle (30,2);
    cout<<" Charmander has "<<charmander.hp()<<" hp and "<<charmander.dmg()<<" damage.\n";
    cout<<" Bulbasaur has "<<bulbasaur.hp()<<" hp and "<<bulbasaur.dmg()<<" damage.\n";
    cout<<" Squirtle has "<<squirtle.hp()<<" hp and "<<squirtle.dmg()<<" damage.\n";

}

//pokemain.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "stats.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout<<charmander.hp();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables `charmander`, `bulbausar` and `squirtle` are being declared inside the constructor. Put them in your main and it should work.

```
int main(void) {
    pokemon charmander(25,3);
    pokemon bulbausar(25,3);
    pokemon squirtle(25,3);

    cout<<" Charmander has "<<charmander.hp()<<" hp and "<<charmander.dmg()<<" damage.\n";
    cout<<" Bulbasaur has "<<bulbasaur.hp()<<" hp and "<<bulbasaur.dmg()<<" damage.\n";
    cout<<" Squirtle has "<<squirtle.hp()<<" hp and "<<squirtle.dmg()<<" damage.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply as well. You both saved me a lot of research

Comment: No problem. I advise you to study what constructors are. I can tell you don't grasp the concept fully. You can start here: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/oop-condestructors/constructors.html

Comment: thanks for that link, I am currently in C++ in college, and its really hard to understand my teacher because of her accent.

Answer (score 1):

`charmander` is declared in the constructor for the `pokemon` class, which means that's the only place it's visible. You probably want to move those declarations and the code that uses them to `main`.

Declaring an instance of a class in the constructor for that same class will cause an endless loop, anyway -- think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiated the class itself. When creating a class it is very possible to have instances of that same class as a recursive instance. That being said the program does not know where you are coming from in your declaration. In order to fix you error, remove the declaration of the pokemon to the main part of the program.

```
int main()
{
    pokemon c;

    cout << "C has " << c.hp() << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Will most likely work.